# How to add bunch of "N's" at the end of file in python?

Tags: python

I have a fasta file that contain multiple sequences and all i wanted to do is to add 64 N's at the end of the each sequence.

Here is an example of input file

```
>164778
AATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTACAACAAATACTTGGCACTTTTATAACCCAACTGTATGGTATAATCGACA
TCTGTGTTATGAAAGGAACTTGATTTGTTGTTAACATAAGCAATCACCATGAATACCTGATAATATTTACAAGTATTGGC
ATTACTCGAATAAGATAATTAATGTAATCATGTTAACAATTTATAATCTAATTGAAACCTCCTTTGTGTGTGGTTTCCAA
TTGGGCAATAAGAGTTTATAC
>164779
AAATCACTTTCAGTGGAAAATTATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTGCCGGCCCTCAAATCAACGCAACCCAAAACCTATTAAT
TATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTTTTTCAATCAACTACGACTATTAATTATATTTGATGATAATGAATGAAATGACACCATG
GTTATATAAAAAATATGTCAAAAGCTATTCTTAATAGGGTTT
```

I would like to get this out

```
>chr
AATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTACAACAAATACTTGGCACTTTTATAACCCAACTGTATGGTATAATCGACA
TCTGTGTTATGAAAGGAACTTGATTTGTTGTTAACATAAGCAATCACCATGAATACCTGATAATATTTACAAGTATTGGC
ATTACTCGAATAAGATAATTAATGTAATCATGTTAACAATTTATAATCTAATTGAAACCTCCTTTGTGTGTGGTTTCCAA
TTGGGCAATAAGAGTTTATACNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAATCACTTTCAGTGGAAAATTATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTGCCGGCCCTCAAATCAACGCAACCCAAAACCTATTAATTATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTTTTTCAATCAACTACGACTATTAATTATATTTGATGATAATGAATGAAATGACACCATG
GTTATATAAAAAATATGTCAAAAGCTATTCTTAATAGGGTTT
```

The code i have right now is adding the N's at the end of the each line and not at the end of each sequence.

```
import textwrap

result = list()
spacer = "N" * 64

with open ("join_fasta_test.fasta", 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.startswith(">"):
            result.append(line)
            result.append(spacer)

print result
result2 = "".join(result)
print result2
result3 = '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(result2, 80))
print result3

with open("join_fasta_test_out.fasta", 'w') as fh_out:
    fh_out.write(">chr")
    fh_out.write("\n")
    fh_out.write(result3)
```

Comment: What seperates sequences? How can you tell when a sequence is *over*.

Comment: Your description and sample output don't quite match up. I'd expect your output to contain all `>{number}` lines too, followed by the sequence with only the spacer added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply of on writing a line until you can test the next; that way you can read the file and write out in one go, no need to hold the whole thing in memory:

```
spacer = "N" * 64

with open ("join_fasta_test.fasta", 'r') as fh_in, \
        open("join_fasta_test_out.fasta", 'w') as fh_out:
     prev = next(fh_in)  # first line
     for line in fh_in:
         if line.startswith('>'):
            prev = prev.rstrip('\n') + spacer + '\n'
         fh_out.write(prev)
         prev = line
     fh_out.write(prev.rstrip('\n') + spacer + '\n')
```

So `prev` is at all times the preceding line, and it is only written after inspecting the 'current' line, adding on the spacer if the current line starts with `>`.

Demo:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> sample = '''\
... >164778
... AATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTACAACAAATACTTGGCACTTTTATAACCCAACTGTATGGTATAATCGACA
... TCTGTGTTATGAAAGGAACTTGATTTGTTGTTAACATAAGCAATCACCATGAATACCTGATAATATTTACAAGTATTGGC
... ATTACTCGAATAAGATAATTAATGTAATCATGTTAACAATTTATAATCTAATTGAAACCTCCTTTGTGTGTGGTTTCCAA
... TTGGGCAATAAGAGTTTATAC
... >164779
... AAATCACTTTCAGTGGAAAATTATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTGCCGGCCCTCAAATCAACGCAACCCAAAACCTATTAAT
... TATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTTTTTCAATCAACTACGACTATTAATTATATTTGATGATAATGAATGAAATGACACCATG
... GTTATATAAAAAATATGTCAAAAGCTATTCTTAATAGGGTTT
... '''
>>> spacer = "N" * 64
>>> fh_in = iter(sample.splitlines(True))
>>> fh_out = StringIO()
>>> prev = next(fh_in)  # first line
>>> for line in fh_in:
...    if line.startswith('>'):
...        prev = prev.rstrip('\n') + spacer + '\n'
...    fh_out.write(prev)
...    prev = line
... 
>>> fh_out.write(prev.rstrip('\n') + spacer + '\n')
>>> print fh_out.getvalue()
>164778
AATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTACAACAAATACTTGGCACTTTTATAACCCAACTGTATGGTATAATCGACA
TCTGTGTTATGAAAGGAACTTGATTTGTTGTTAACATAAGCAATCACCATGAATACCTGATAATATTTACAAGTATTGGC
ATTACTCGAATAAGATAATTAATGTAATCATGTTAACAATTTATAATCTAATTGAAACCTCCTTTGTGTGTGGTTTCCAA
TTGGGCAATAAGAGTTTATACNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>164779
AAATCACTTTCAGTGGAAAATTATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTGCCGGCCCTCAAATCAACGCAACCCAAAACCTATTAAT
TATAAAACCTATTAATTTATTTTTTCAATCAACTACGACTATTAATTATATTTGATGATAATGAATGAAATGACACCATG
GTTATATAAAAAATATGTCAAAAGCTATTCTTAATAGGGTTTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Comment: It worked but not the way i wanted. I can modify this to suit my needs. One question though. Why are you writing to the output file twice?

Comment: @upendra: by the time the input file is done, you have one remaining line in `prev` that still needs writing out.